# How to make Javascript (raining matrix code) as a background of the website

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem I encounter is that I dont know how to overlay a text, image, and video on a javascript. I tried to find it on youtube and google but I find no answer. Can somebody help me? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: black">
  

    <canvas id="Matrix" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>

  


</body>
</html>
```

```
html {
    background: black;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('Matrix');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const katakana = 'アァカサタナハマヤャラワガザダバパイィキシチニヒミリヰギジヂビピウゥクスツヌフムユュルグズブヅプエェケセテネヘメレヱゲゼデベペオォコソトノホモヨョロヲゴゾドボポヴッン';
const latin = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const nums = '0123456789';

const alphabet = katakana + latin + nums;

const fontSize = 16;
const columns = canvas.width/fontSize;

const rainDrops = [];

for( let x = 0; x < columns; x++ ) {
    rainDrops[x] = 1;
}

const draw = () => {
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    
    context.fillStyle = '#0F0';
    context.font = fontSize + 'px monospace';

    for(let i = 0; i < rainDrops.length; i++)
    {
        const text = alphabet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length));
        context.fillText(text, i*fontSize, rainDrops[i]*fontSize);
        
        if(rainDrops[i]*fontSize > canvas.height && Math.random() > 0.975){
            rainDrops[i] = 0;
        }
        rainDrops[i]++;
    }
};

setInterval(draw, 30);
```

I am expecting the javascript to be the background of my entire website while only using HTML,CSS, and JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5278505/12511801) solution, you can use the properties `position: absolute` to place elements above the canvas.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('Matrix');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

const katakana = 'アァカサタナハマヤャラワガザダバパイィキシチニヒミリヰギジヂビピウゥクスツヌフムユュルグズブヅプエェケセテネヘメレヱゲゼデベペオォコソトノホモヨョロヲゴゾドボポヴッン';
const latin = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const nums = '0123456789';

const alphabet = katakana + latin + nums;

const fontSize = 16;
const columns = canvas.width / fontSize;

const rainDrops = [];

for (let x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
  rainDrops[x] = 1;
}

const draw = () => {
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05)';
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  context.fillStyle = '#0F0';
  context.font = fontSize + 'px monospace';

  for (let i = 0; i < rainDrops.length; i++) {
    const text = alphabet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length));
    context.fillText(text, i * fontSize, rainDrops[i] * fontSize);

    if (rainDrops[i] * fontSize > canvas.height && Math.random() > 0.975) {
      rainDrops[i] = 0;
    }
    rainDrops[i]++;
  }
};

setInterval(draw, 30);
```

```css
html {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}


/* Color of the text - you can change it as you need. */

div {
  color: red;
}


/* These are the properties applied to div that has the "innerDiv" class - you can change it as you need. */

.innerDiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="Matrix" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="innerDiv">
    <span>This is an title example:</span>
    <br/>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```